# How to parse this xml file with duplicated elements at the same level

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

After hours checking some other answers around i can't find a way to read this specific xml file properly from a rss feed. I have one element duplicated at the same level: language

Here is the rss feed:

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:veinteminutos="http://www.20minutos.es/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>20minutos.es</title>
    <link>http://www.20minutos.es/</link>
    <description> 
    </description>
    <language>es</language>
    <pubDate>Fri, 02 Jan 2015 17:02:55 +0100</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Fri, 02 Jan 2015 17:02:55 +0100</lastBuildDate>
    <ttl>2</ttl>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>2</sy:updateFrequency>
    <sy:updateBase>2015-01-02T17:02:55+01:00</sy:updateBase>
    <dc:language>es</dc:language>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

And here my class declaration but i'm not sure how i must handle it:

```
public class Channel
{
    @Element(name = "pubDate")
    private String pubDate;

    @Element(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Element(name = "link")
    private String link;

    @Element(name = "lastBuildDate")
    private String lastBuildDate;

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private ArrayList<Item> item;

    @Element(name = "language")
    private String language;

    @Element(name = "ttl")
    private String ttl;

    @Element(name = "updatePeriod")
    private String updatePeriod;

    @Element(name = "updateFrequency")
    private String updateFrequency;

    @Element(name = "updateBase")
    private String updateBase;

    @Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")
    @Element(name = "language")
    private String dclanguage;

    public String getPubDate ()
    {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate (String pubDate)
    {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLink ()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink (String link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getLastBuildDate ()
    {
        return lastBuildDate;
    }

    public void setLastBuildDate (String lastBuildDate)
    {
        this.lastBuildDate = lastBuildDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItem ()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem (ArrayList<Item> item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getLanguage ()
    {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage (String language)
    {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getTtl ()
    {
        return ttl;
    }

    public void setTtl (String ttl)
    {
        this.ttl = ttl;
    }

    public String getUpdatePeriod() {
        return updatePeriod;
    }

    public void setUpdatePeriod(String updatePeriod) {
        this.updatePeriod = updatePeriod;
    }

    public String getUpdateFrequency() {
        return updateFrequency;
    }

    public void setUpdateFrequency(String updateFrequency) {
        this.updateFrequency = updateFrequency;
    }

    public String getUpdateBase() {
        return updateBase;
    }

    public void setUpdateBase(String updateBase) {
        this.updateBase = updateBase;
    }

    public String getDclanguage() {
        return dclanguage;
    }

    public void setDclanguage(String dclanguage) {
        this.dclanguage = dclanguage;
    }


}
```

I get the error "*org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation of name '**language**' on field 'language' private*"

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I assume you get the problem because `@Element(name = "language")` is evaluated before `@Namespace(reference="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")`. Can you make sure this is not the case?

Comment: I also tried placing @Naamespace() before the @Element but i got the same error....i'm not even sure if this @Namespace() call is right, and/or if i must do it also for the 1sr <language> element...

Comment: Did you try the "hacky" way with just `@Element(name = "dc:language")` eventhough it is not very clean?

Comment: when i try the "hacky" way i got this error `org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'language' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=language, required=true, type=void) on field 'language' private` pretty similar to the previous one :-/

Comment: Try adding `@Namespace(reference = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")`

Comment: Nothing, i got the same error `org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation of name 'language' on field 'language' private` . Maybe i must add a @Namespace() reference too to the 1st <language> element? i dont know.....

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry to say, but this is a internal error.

I have the same problem, I modified the code to get what is need to read RSS/ATOM feed. I downloaded the source of the simple xml framework to see whats the problem.

In the Composite class, the method readElement (who search the annotation with the name) ignore the prefix and dont find ATOM's or Itunes element, i changed this and this worked.

Lets hope someone change in a future version.